# Best way to keep a pipe open after a remote close

Tags: c#, .net, pipe, named-pipes

Using [this tutorial](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-named-pipes-in-c-windows/) i came up with the code below. My client is ran frequently. Its activated via clicks and possibly can be launched twice at the same moment in certain circumstance. I am worried one client may close while another client opens which causes the pipe to be closed in that slim few milliseconds. Whats the best way to keep the pipe open?

```
    static public void ThreadStartServer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("mytestpipe"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Server] Pipe created {0}", pipeStream.GetHashCode());

                pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
                Console.WriteLine("[Server] Pipe connection established");

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
                {
                    string temp;
                    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are two clients connected to the same pipe? Can that ever work out?

Answer (score 1):

Make your pipe server multi-threaded, with one thread dedicated to listening. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584211/named-pipes-usage-multiple-clients-one-server-multiple-parallel-requests/5584764#5584764) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451805/windows-named-pipe-issue-error-code-233-alternates/4475816#4475816):